Datasets sum using xarray
I have two datasets with three dimensions: latitude, longitude and time. Latitude and longitude dimensions are the same, while time dimension has a 1 day offset. They have multiple variables and I'm interested in one specifically. The datasets are as follows:
nd4 = xarray.open_mfdataset("../chec_prep/TAG_PREP/04/*.nc")
nd5 = xarray.open_mfdataset("../chec_prep/TAG_PREP/05/*.nc")
print(ds4)
print(ds5)


<xarray.Dataset> Size: 15MB
Dimensions:                (time: 11, latitude: 241, longitude: 241)
Coordinates:
  * latitude               (latitude) float32 964B 20.0 19.75 ... -39.75 -40.0
  * longitude              (longitude) float32 964B -80.0 -79.75 ... -20.0
  * time                   (time) datetime64[ns] 88B 2023-04-24 ... 2023-05-04



<xarray.Dataset> Size: 15MB
Dimensions:                (time: 11, latitude: 241, longitude: 241)
Coordinates:
  * latitude               (latitude) float32 964B 20.0 19.75 ... -39.75 -40.0
  * longitude              (longitude) float32 964B -80.0 -79.75 ... -20.0
  * time                   (time) datetime64[ns] 88B 2023-04-25 ... 2023-05-05

I need to obtain a third dataset with the sum of this variable 'tagged_precip'.
First, I evaluated the total sum of precipitation in both datasets.
nd4 = xarray.open_mfdataset("../chec_prep/TAG_PREP/04/*.nc")
nd5 = xarray.open_mfdataset("../chec_prep/TAG_PREP/05/*.nc")
print(nd4['tagged_precip'].sum().values)
print(nd5['tagged_precip'].sum().values)


2682132500.0
3773539800.0

Now, if I summed those two datasets, I would have as the result the same value if I summed the separate values. So, I did a simple sum of both datasets as:
nd6 = nd4 + nd5
print(nd6)
<xarray.Dataset> Size: 14MB
Dimensions:                (latitude: 241, longitude: 241, time: 10)
Coordinates:
  * latitude               (latitude) float32 964B 20.0 19.75 ... -39.75 -40.0
  * longitude              (longitude) float32 964B -80.0 -79.75 ... -20.0
  * time                   (time) datetime64[ns] 80B 2023-04-25 ... 2023-05-04

But the result here is the intersection of the time dimension and the sum of all values is incorrect:
print(nd6['tagged_precip'].sum().values)
print(nd5['tagged_precip'].sum().values + nd4['tagged_precip'].sum().values)
2710198300.0
6455672300.0

Then, I tried opening all files simultaneosly:
np = xarray.open_mfdataset("../chec_prep/TAG_PREP/*/*.nc", combine='nested', concat_dim='time').groupby('time').sum(dim='time')
np['tagged_precip'].sum().values == nd4['tagged_precip'].sum().values + nd5['tagged_precip'].sum().values

Which returns a True statement. However, looking into each array, the numbers do not match. Specifically, the only operation that returns False is:
print('nd4: ', nd4['tagged_precip'].sum(dim=['latitude','longitude']).values[10])
print('nd5: ', nd5['tagged_precip'].sum(dim=['latitude','longitude']).values[9])
print('np: ', np['tagged_precip'].sum(dim=['latitude','longitude']).values[10])
print('nd4 + nd5: ', (nd4['tagged_precip'].sum(dim=['latitude','longitude']).values[10] + nd5['tagged_precip'].sum(dim=['latitude','longitude']).values[9]))
print('nd4 + nd5 - np: ', nd4['tagged_precip'].sum(dim=['latitude','longitude']).values[10] + nd5['tagged_precip'].sum(dim=['latitude','longitude']).values[9] - np['tagged_precip'].sum(dim=['latitude','longitude']).values[10])

nd4:  2653497900.0
nd5:  28065528.0
np:  2681563600.0
nd4 + nd5:  2681563400.0
nd4 + nd5 - np:  -256.0

Okay. Now, that sum does not add up. I could not understand what is happening here. Any help is accepted. I am getting a little confused with all this, since I have never worked much with programming.

It's not clear to me what behavior you want - is it "for each day, the sum of the rain on that day and the day beforehand?"

Yes! I want that behaviour. Sorry I could not explain it very well.
